# Using Interop.Outlook with the new Outlook

Tags: c#, security, outlook, office-automation, com-automation

I am trying to figure out how to work with the new outlook that should be released at the end of 2024 as the default outlook( [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627) ).

When using the new outlook by switching the toggle button [image]

I am not able to initialize the Interop application: `_application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;`

I am getting the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Operation unavailable
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))'

Any idea what am I missing? Is it possible I can no longer use this API anymore with the new outlook ? I cannot migrate to web add-ins because I must be able to communicate with outlook from my application.

Comment: Looks like support for COM Automation, and therefore VBA, support is gone in the New Outlook: https://www.accessforever.org/post/the-new-outlook-and-access-vba - which is a very surprising move from Microsoft because automation is **the** reason Office remains entrenched in businesses, this feels like killing-the-golden-goose to me.

Comment: Here's the Feedback Portal entry where we can have our complaints ignored: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/bd492fa1-e65b-ee11-a81c-000d3ae46fcb

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/one-outlook The "Supported scenarios" table will give you an idea what to expect next and what scenarios  you might have in mind doing isn't even planned.

Answer (score -2):

The new Outlook (Monarch) is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar, not desktop Outlook (a part of the Office suite), which is still fully supported.

Monarch indeed has no programmatically accessible API besides Web (JS) addins.

If you don't like the fact that Monarch has no usable API, [take up it with Microsoft](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: I don't fully understand. Today I work with Office API against Outlook. Would I be able to do it after the new outlook would be released as default?

Comment: _"The new Outlook (Monarch) is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar"_ - that's not [what Microsoft says](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/new-outlook-for-windows-available-to-all-office-insiders).

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB - no. It is a totally different product. Similar to Outlook Express in the past.

Comment: @Dai - where do you see MS saying Monarch will replace desktop Outlook in the near future? They might replace it years in the future when the two achieve feature and API parity, but it is not there yet. And won't be for years.